# How To Create A Table Search Bar Using JAVASCRIPT To Search A CSV File uploaded by user?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How Do I Implement A search bar for user uploaded CSV File displayed as table in the Webpage.

Basically i am trying to make a webpage which takes csv file shows it as table and through a search bar it searches specified word form the table.

```
html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=in, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Enter Student Name">
    <input type="file" accept=".csv" id="picker">
    <table id="table"
    ></table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
window.onload=() => {
    var reader = new FileReader(),
        picker = document.getElementById("picker"),
        table = document.getElementById("table");

    picker.onchange = () => reader.readAsText(picker.files[0]);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        let csv = reader.result;
        table.innerHTML ="";
        let rows = csv.split("\r\n")
        for(let row of rows){
            let cols = row.match(/(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\")|([^\",]+)/g);
            if (cols!=null){

                let tr = table.insertRow();
                for(let col of cols){
                    let td = tr.insertCell();
                    td.innerHTML = col;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make a search bar from a yt video but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a search bar for a user uploaded CSV file displayed as a table in a webpage by using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. Here is one approach to get you started:

1. Parse the CSV file into an array of objects: You can use a library like [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/) to parse the uploaded CSV file into a JavaScript array of objects. It makes easier for searching in object/array instead of raw csv string.
2. Create an HTML table from the parsed data: You can create an HTML table and populate it with the data from the parsed CSV file.
3. Add a search bar: You can add an input field for searching and a search button to the webpage.
4. Search the table: You can use JavaScript to search the table for the entered word and highlight the matching rows. You can use the .filter() method to filter the array of objects, and the .includes() method to check if the search term is present in each object.
5. Update the table: After filtering the array, you can update the HTML table to only show the matching rows.

Comment: did you use chatgpt at all to write any part of this answer?